# Tomcat no longer logging errors to catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

For some reason, exceptions and stack traces are no longer printing to catalina.out in my java web application.

Application deployment messages and System.out.println() work fine. I'm using Quartz Scheduler in my project which necessitates the inclusion of log4j library.

**log4j.properties**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=ALL
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content=ALL
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=ALL
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN" "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="httpclient">
        <level value="warn"/> 
    </logger>

    <logger name="httpclient.wire">
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I do not have a logging.properties file. It was all working until recently, and I'm a bit stumped after a couple of hours of digging around. If anyone has an answer it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have an error-page handler for code 500 in the web.xml?  If so, NPEs and other exceptions will be handled there and not sent to catalina.out.

Comment: Hi Mark - nope, no handler there.